# Speed up large set of mysql update queries

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I need to update about 2.5 million rows in a mysql table. I tried to do this in a for loop, but this takes a couple of hours to execute. The `id` column is primary key.

How can I speed this up?

My Python (with pandas dataframe) code:

```
dataframe = to_update_rows_dataframe

for i,row in dataframe.iterrows():

    sql = "UPDATE table SET `val1` = %.4f , `val2` = %.6f WHERE `id` = %d;" % (row['val1'], row['val2'], row['id'])
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
```

Thanks

EDIT:

```
dataframe = to_update_rows

string_list_val1 = []
string_list_val2 = []
id_list = dataframe['id'].tolist()

for i,row in dataframe.iterrows():

    string_list_val1.append('when %d THEN %.4f' % (row['id'], row['val1']))
    string_list_val2.append('when %d THEN %.6f' % (row['id'], row['val2']))

s1 = ' '.join(string_list_val1)
s2 = ' '.join(string_list_val2) 
s3 = ','.join(map(str,id_list))

query = "UPDATE table SET `val1` = (CASE id %s ELSE `val1` END), `val2` = (CASE id %s ELSE `val2` END) WHERE id IN( %s );" % (s1,s2,s3)
cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

However building this query-string still takes a lot of time to build.

Is there a way to speed up the for loop for the string?

I read: http://waymoot.org/home/python_string/ 
Did I make a mistake with the implementation of method 4?

Another question is: What happens if the query is too large?

i.e. the phpmyadmin/mysql timeout kicks in.? Is there a maximum number of rows? can there be inserts in the table during the execution of the query?

Thanks

Comment: You should use sql bulk update for this instead of a for loop

Comment: @Stasel , thanks for your input. I updated the question can you maybe look at my other questions?

Answer (score 0):

This way the for loop is completely gone and runs in under 1 second. The bulk update execution time not tested yet:

```
dataframe = to_update_rows

s1 = ' when ' +  dataframe['id'].map(str) + ' THEN ' + dataframe['val1'].round(4).map(str) 
s2 = ' when ' +  dataframe['id'].map(str) + ' THEN ' + dataframe['val2'].round(6).map(str)

s1 = " ".join(s1.tolist())
s2 = " ".join(s2.tolist())
s3 = ",".join(map(str, dataframe['id'].tolist()))

query = "UPDATE table SET `val1` = (CASE id %s ELSE `val1` END), `cost` = (CASE id %s ELSE `val2` END) WHERE id IN( %s );" % (s1,s2,s3)
cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
```